# Excel Nesting if clause to find names and assign a value

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

### To nest or not to nest?

I am given a list of Emp. ID and Names in two columns

> Emp. ID  Name
>
> DOEJ   Doe, John

Depending on the name I want to assign a shift number to the employee in another column.
Here is the if statement I set up to search for the name and assign a shift. But I think there must be a better more efficient way.

```
=IF(Table4[@Name]="B,Cis",1,
IF(Table4[@Name]="Petty, Richard",1,
IF(Table4[@Name]="Trump, Donald",1,
IF(Table4[@Name]="Johnny, John",1,
IF(Table4[@Name]="Carlos, Mencina",1,
IF(Table4[@Name]="Smith, Smith",1,
IF(Table4[@Name]="Day, Conner",2,
IF(Table4[@Name]="Macho, Man",2,
IF(Table4[@Name]="Doe, John",2,
IF(Table4[@Name]="Sandy, Johnron",2,
IF(Table4[@Name]="Conner, Donaldson",2,
IF(Table4[@Name]="Randy, Jones",2,
IF(Table4[@Name]="Cook, Joseph",3,
IF(Table4[@Name]="Cooper, Johnny",3,
IF(Table4[@Name]="Rodrigo, Cooker",3,
IF(Table4[@Name]="Potter, Copper",3,
IF(Table4[@Name]="Rodrigo, Gonzolez","A",
IF(Table4[@Name]="Ronny, Ponny","A",
IF(Table4[@Name]="Rodrigo, Coolio","A",
IF(Table4[@Name]="Roma, Coma","B",
IF(Table4[@Name]="Star, Como","B","N/A")))))))))))))))))))))
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but this formula makes it seem that you have fixed assignments depending only on the employee name. That being the case, why not just manually add a Shift column to Table4?

Answer (score 1):

Just make a table in another sheet and keep that updated with the employee/shift mapping. Then use a vlookup formula to get the shift from the employee name.

Assuming you call the other sheet "Shifts", employee name is in column A, shift code is in column B.

```
=VLOOKUP(Table4[@Name],Shifts!$A:$B,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: I've not seen the at sign (@) documented in Excel's structured table reference materials, and I've not been able to enter it as a column reference Excel 2007  e.g: =Table1[@Name].  What am I missing?

Comment: I didn't actually test it, I just copied the syntax from the question. I never use Excel tables, so I'm not sure if it's right or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `and(...)`

```
=if(and(...stuff that would produce 1...),1, if(and(...stuff that would produce 2...), 2, ...
```

Personally, I would use vba for something like this. I don't suppose you'd be open to that.

Comment: I don't have any experience with VBA but am willing to learn. How would you go about doing this in VBA?

Comment: If you have a developer tab, click it and hit the Visual Basic button. There you can write a subroutine for this. If you don't have that tab, you can get it by going to file-->options-->Customize Ribbon and check Developer.

Comment: I have the tab and know how to open VB. I just don't know what to program to get what I need.

Comment: Well, once you hit visual basic, go to insert-->module and you should get a spot to start typing code. Try something like 'sub run() for i=1 to 10 if cells(i,1)="some name" then cells(i,2)=1 else if ... end if next i end sub (the i represents each row number and the second number in cells(..., ...) represents a column number.